# How to split pipe-separated (|) values of a column in a datatable and retain other columns in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataset

I have a datatable named dt1 like this

```
name    age  color
a|b|c   20   red
d|e|f   30   green
x|y|z   40   blue
```

I want to split the first column that is pipe-separated (|) into 3 columns and copy the rest of the columns as it is

```
n1  n2  n3  age  color
a   b   c   20   red
d   e   f   30   green
x   y   z   40   blue
```

Can someone please advice me on how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to say more about the environment you are working in and how often you want to do this. In SQL you can use the STRING_SPLIT method, on the other hand if you are using EF and C# you would use string.Split and copy the results to a new record that you will save to the output table.

Comment: I already have a datatable that looks like the example I have given above in my C# code. I am fine with either modifying or making a new datatable. I am using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("age", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("color", typeof(string));
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"a|b|c", 20, "red"});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"d|e|f", 30, "green"});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "x|y|z", 40, "blue" });

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("n1", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("n2", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("n3", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("age", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("color", typeof(string));

            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.AsEnumerable())
            {
                string[] splitData = row.Field<string>(0).Split(new char[] {'|'});
                dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { splitData[0], splitData[1], splitData[2], row.Field<int>(1), row.Field<string>(2) });
            }

        }
    }
}
```